# Have arrow toggle back (0deg) when "x" close icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on an accordion and have it close to what I need it to be. However, I can't seem to have the arrow rotate back to 0 degrees after the close "x" icon has been clicked. The toggle closes but the arrow stays in a downward position.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82y7zb97/5/)

```
  $('#main').each(function () {
      var $accordian = $(this);
      $accordian.find('.view-m').on('click', function () {
          $accordian.find('.mobile-content-body').slideUp();
          $accordian.find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
          if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $accordian.find('.close').click(function () {
                  $(this).parent().slideUp(500);
                  $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in this line:

```
$(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
```

you are searching for the arrow **inside** the X button. you need to go 2 elements up, and search there:

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/82y7zb97/6/)**</kbd>

```
  $('#main').each(function () {
      var $accordian = $(this);
      $accordian.find('.view-m').on('click', function () {
          $accordian.find('.mobile-content-body').slideUp();
          $accordian.find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
          if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $accordian.find('.close').click(function () {
                  $(this).parent().slideUp(500);
                  $(this).parent().parent().find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
```

with

```
 $(this).parent().prev('.view-m').find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5o9scL/)